# Xcode 7.3 framework build succeeded but no output

Tags: frameworks, xcode7.3

I made my own framework following the guide of https://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios and it was working with Xcode 7.2. When I upgraded Xcode to 7.3, the framework build succeeded but NO OUTPUT. I tried to insert

```
unset TOOLCHAINS
```

on top of the script but it still does not work. Does anyone have a workaround? Thanks in advance.